# Closed form solution of stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to find the closed form solution of the following SDE,

$$dX(t) = (\alpha - \beta X) dt + X dW(t),$$
where W(t) is the standard BM.

$\textbf{My attempt}:$

First I solve for the following differential equation,

$$dU(t) = -\beta U(t) dt + U(t) dW(t).$$ On solving this, I get,

$$U(t) = {e}^{-\Delta t + W(t)}$$ where, $\Delta = \Big(\beta+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$.

Now, I know that, $$X(t) = U(t)\Bigg(X(0) + \alpha \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{U(s)}ds\Bigg)$$
On plugging the value of U(t), I get,
$$X(t) = {e}^{-\Delta t + W(t)}\Bigg(X(0) + \alpha \int_{0}^{t} {e}^{\Delta s - W(s)} ds\Bigg).$$

How do I solve $\int_{0}^{t} {e}^{\Delta s - W(s)} ds$ ? This is where I am stuck for a long time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by solve $\int_0^t e^{\Delta s - W(s)}\,ds$? You've already found $X(t)$ as a function of $W$. What kind of solution would you like?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to solve that integral to the final solution is not in terms of any integrals. Eventually I'd like to see what happens when $t \rightarrow \infty$. If I have a closed form solution, it'd be easier to do that.

Comment: See here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/solve-the-following-sde-mathrmdx-t-ab-x-t-mathrmdt-c-x-t-mat